# Replacing observableArray data when there is a beforeRemove handler causes refresh problems

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a system of notifications that refreshes on a timer. Say there are 4 records in the queue. If you're viewing the queue when the refresh happens, the underlying notifications array is replaced by a new array that also has 4 records. This displays fine.

But if I have a `beforeRemove` notification in place on the `foreach`, what happens is that I briefly see a refresh where 8 items display, and then it goes back to 4 items. This happens no matter how I update the array (simple replacement, removeAll and then replace, set to an empty array and add one at a time, etc.) This happens even if I never try to remove an element from the array.

This is quite frustrating, because I'd really like to be able to apply a transition, but can't figure out how to make it work without this glitch.

## Update with code sample:

Here's the markup

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: notifications, beforeRemove: hideNotification}">
<tr>
<td data-bind="text: $root.message($data)"></td>
<td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.acknowledge.bind($root, $data)">Got It</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here's the code (note that it's Typescript and that I'm using knockout-es5 so I can use less parentheses):

```
class Model
{
    private loginId: number = (the current value; details not relevant)

    notifications: Notification[] = [];

    constructor()
    {
        ko.track(this);
    }


    update()
    {
        var self = this;
        $.get(`/api/notifications/${self.loginId.toString()}`).done((data) =>
        {
            self.notifications.removeAll();
            self.notifications = data;
        });
    }

}

var model = new Model();

$(function ()
{
    ko.applyBindings(model);

    model.update();

    setInterval(model.update.bind(model), 5000);
});
```

The meat of this is the `update` method. This is called every 5 seconds and simply replaces the `notifications` array with the current data. As I say above, if there's no `beforeRemove` keyword, it works perfectly. If that is there, and there are, say, 4 notifications in the queue, the displayed table jumps from 4 to 8 rows and then back to 4, even though the array is cleared before the add, so *there are never actually 8 rows in the array*.

Comment: This kind of stuff is commonplace in programming and is often times app-specific. You must write code to queue or buffer the new changes until after the `beforeRemove` stuff is done. The code should wait until your app is no longer in an _updating_ or _removing_ state.

Comment: But what I'm saying is that `beforeRemove` is never called. This glitch happens if I just replace the array with the same data it had before, without removing anything.

Comment: Some code would be helpful then. It's hard to see exactly what your app is doing. [Here's a fiddle to get you started](https://jsfiddle.net/xpq4vm31/)

Comment: @RyanWheale: thanks for the fiddle, although I'm not sure I can get a version working because it depends on async data from the server and I'm not sure how to mock this in the fiddle. But I added a code sample to my question. Hope that helps, and thanks for your eyes on this.

Comment: Try replacing $.get with your own function in the fiddle... $.get = function() { return Promise.resolve([...]); }.  This will be async.  You can make around with setTimeouts to simulate latency.  Just remember that ".done" will need to replaced with ".then"

Comment: Are you using a with block?  I've noticed that a with block takes a read dependency on everything inside it can have strange redraw outcomes

Comment: What does the hideNotification method do?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank . i assume you have some kind of fadeout in your hide function. Did you try other easing functions on fadeout? https://jsfiddle.net/P8GVq/105/

Comment: Please show your `hideNotification` code.

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but second previous comments: we need a repro to be able to help you. Otherwise we're stabbing at solutions in the dark. If you don't know how to mock out the API bit that's okay, just provide us with *everything else to repro* (but as little as possible), and in addition post the responses we can expect from the API.

Comment: On a side note, it helps to either (preferably) remove the dependency on libraries to simplify the example, or if they're relevant to the problem add them as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you want. Click on the "Update" button to asynchronously update (no transition). Click on an item to remove it (with a transition).

https://jsfiddle.net/xpq4vm31/3/

Relevant code:

```
update()
{
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.updating = true;
        self.notifications.removeAll();
        self.notifications(["First", "Second", "Third");        
        self.updating = false;
    });
}

hideNotification(element, index, item)
{
    if (this.updating) {
       $(element).remove();
    } else {
       $(element).fadeOut(2000, function(){$(this).remove();});
    }
}
```